# Downloading Component Failed in android studio

Tags: android, sdk, components

Android Studio components can not be download. i tried different windows and different versions of android studio but still can not solve this issue. check out the screenshot i have attached and please help me to solve this. i am working on a project and its on pending now. [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGpq4.png)

Comment: Error show connection read time out....check your internet connection is working or not

Comment: yes internet is working . this downloads other packages but only few packages failed to download